# How to filter href links by **class** or **div id** values when processing a webpage using BeautifulSoup in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have a html file with different **class** and **div** attributes as follows

```
<div id="meat">             
    <div id="tag_nav" class="font2 pad2">
Comics: 
<a id="tag_nav_random" href="/random">Random</a>
<a id="tag_nav_popular" href="/tag/popular">Most Popular</a>
<a href="/comics">All</a>
<a href="/tag/cats">Cats</a>
<a href="/tag/grammar">Grammar</a>
<a href="/tag/food">Food</a>
<a href="/tag/animals">Animals</a>
<a href="/tag/tech">Tech</a>
```

```
<li>
        <div class="bg_comic">
        <a href="/comics/mantis_shrimp"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/theoatmeal-img/thumbnails/mantis_shrimp.png" alt="Why the mantis shrimp is my new favorite animal" class="border0" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="category_and_view">
    </li>
```

I want to extract all the links in my html page which only belong to class **bg_comic** and ignore other  tags which may belong to different classes. 
I am trying the following but it isn't working:

```
links=soup.find_all("a",class_="bg_comic")
for tag in links:
    link=tag.get('href',None)
```

In the above example, the **link** variable should have the value **/comics/mantis_shrimp** and not any other value. But my code isn't printing anything.

What am I doing wrong? How do we filter links by **class** or **div id** values when processing a webpage using BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `a` tag with `bg_comic` class in the html, but `div` tag with `bg_comic`.

Modifying your code as follow will solve your problem.

```
links = soup.find_all("div", class_="bg_comic") # a -> div
for tag in links:
    lilnk = tag.a.get('href', None) # tag.get -> tag.a.get
```

Alternatively, you can use [css selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
links = soup.select("div.bg_comic a")
for tag in links:
    link = tag.get('href', None)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working both ways. 
I am new to BeautifulSoup and I tried searching for more examples to use find_all and get methods of soup. But couldn't find any. Can you please share some link where I will get more information about web extract & processing, pattern matching etc like this?

Comment: @AjimBagwan, I recommend you to read [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial). After that? See [What's now?](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/whatnow.html). Book? I don't know.

Comment: @AjimBagwan, For BeautifulSoup, see [BeautifulSoup documentaiton](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc).

Comment: Thank you, weirdname. For everything. :)